# Convert byte array to represent a boolean table in java

Tags: java, arrays, active-directory

I am working in active directory where the login hours are stored as a boolean table.

For reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/iadsuser-property-methods) check get_loginHours method.

I got the values as a byte array of size 21.

The first 3 bytes consist of one day's login permission.

1 byte has 8 bits

```
if the bit is 0 then login access is denied
if the bit is 1 then login is allowed
```

So with 3 bytes I have 24 bits which corresponds to the total hours in the day.

With this byte array I have to check for all the 7 days.

I don't know how to convert the byte array to bits and check all 168 bits which corresponds to 24*7 = 168.

Can someone help me to write a function that uses the byte array to the desired output.

Code which i tried and that didn't work.

```
public static void displayHours(byte[] hours) {
        final String[] DAYS = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getWeekdays();    
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(hours);
        
        for (int day = 1; day <= 7; day++) {
            System.out.printf("Hours allowed for %s%n", DAYS[day]);
            for (int hour = 0; hour <= 24; hour++) {
                int bit = day * 7 + hour;
                boolean allowed = bi.testBit(bit);
                System.out.printf("\tLogin permitted for hour %d?: %b%n", hour, allowed);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: This the value that is stored in active directory and i converted these values to byte array]
Byte array op -> -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-10-1

Comment: I've got something that could help. Could you possibly post a 24 byte hex-escaped test string (the correct hours interpretation of which is known to you) so I can test it? Something like ```0xB4,0xD2,0xEB,0x65,0xB6,0xC,0x97,0x21,0x14,0xF2,0x7A,0xAD,0xA0,0xB9,0x14,0x2F,0x8A,0x6B,0x9F,0x0,0xB7,0xD5,0x99,0xAF```

Comment: Yes, that would be useful - as long as you know what it actually means as far as hours are concerned ;)

Comment: I have updated the question with little more reference btw still i couldn't convert these array value with the desired output

Comment: 'By eye' that pattern would mean every hour available apart from the 2nd third of Saturday. Is that what you think it means?

Comment: Exactly that is how the data is represented last 3 bytes are saturday's data representation. The 0 here is  hour 8am - 4pm of saturday the login access is denied and other hours are accepted.

Comment: No there are 21 bytes in total which corresponds to 7days * 3bytes for each day = 21 total bytes. It corresponds to sunday to saturday and where did you notice 22 bytes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248407/discussion-between-g00se-and-si-2493).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BigInteger(byte[] val)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)) says

> Translates a byte array containing the two's-complement binary representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element. The val array is assumed to be unchanged for the duration of the constructor call.

So you need to traverse the bits starting with the most significant bit (167).

```
public static void displayHours(byte[] hours) {
    final String[] DAYS = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getWeekdays();    
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(hours);
    
    for (int day = 0, bit = hours.length * 8 - 1; day < 7; day++) {
        System.out.printf("Hours allowed for %s%n", DAYS[day + 1]);
        for (int hour = 0; hour < 24; hour++, bit--) {
            boolean allowed = bi.testBit(bit);
            System.out.printf("\tLogin permitted for hour %d?: %b%n", hour, allowed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate this explains everything and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] arr = {12,2,3,4,5,6,12,3,43,43,34,34,5,5,34,1,32,5,12,13,4}; //size 21
    for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j+= 3) {
        String currentDayBitArray = getBitArrayFromByte(arr[j]) + getBitArrayFromByte(arr[j + 1]) + getBitArrayFromByte(arr[j+2]);
        for(int i = 0; i <=23; i++){
            if(currentDayBitArray.charAt(i) == '1') {
                System.out.println("hour : " + i + " had permission allowed");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("hour : " + i + " had permission denied");
            }
        }
      System.out.println("Current day bit array is : " + currentDayBitArray);
    }

    System.out.println();
}

private String getBitArrayFromByte(byte b) {
    return String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString((b + 256) % 256))
          .replace(' ', '0');
}
```

You can do something like that, created a method getBitArrayFromByte to convert from a byte to a bit array as a string (it will replace unnecesary bits representation with 0's so you can have a bit array of length 8)

Build that array for each 3 bytes (meaning one day) and check the bits values